# How to make Structs with Symbolic Variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I would like to make a struct (or cell array) with symbolic variables that I can access like an object using Matlab Symbolic Toolbox (2018b). I would like something like this:

```matlab
    syms car.speed car.weight bus.speed bus.weight
```

Trying the above line returns the following error:

```
Error using syms (line 228)
Invalid variable name.
```

I would like to access the elements like so:

```matlab
    car.KE = 0.5*car.speed^2*car.weight
    bus.KE = 0.5*bus.speed^2*bus.weight
```

This works for normal variables but doesn't seem to work in the symbolic toolbox.

Comment: Doesn’t seem to work? Please post your code that doesn’t work, with the error message. It will help you get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbolic structs do not exist. However, a normal struct with fields containing the symbolic content can be created. i.e.

```
car.speed = sym('car_speed');   car.weight = sym('car_weight');
bus.speed = sym('car_speed');   bus.weight = sym('bus_weight');
```

Now you can go on with:

```
car.KE = 0.5*car.speed^2*car.weight;
bus.KE = 0.5*bus.speed^2*bus.weight;
```

Comment: I had already feared there is no way to do it. I will probably end up doing it as you suggested even if it is not 'clean'.

Comment: @fishlein, Why not just use `car_speed` instead of `car.speed`? What is the point of using a dot there?

Comment: @Cris Luengo It makes it easier to pass a number of variables to a function if its in a struct. I also like to have an uncluttered workspace and sort my variables into structs in which I can group them sensibly.